# Subscribe XAML event to a event handler in a different C# file

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, winui-3

The problem occour when I try to assign (subscribe) a `ToggleButton` to a event handler in a different file (for example: XAML is named `PrimaryPage.xaml` and a C# file is named different like `EventHandler.cs`, not `PrimaryPage.xaml`) in the same solution as I wanted to seperate things up.

Here's what I meant:

1. Create a `ToggleButton` in XAML:

```xml
<ToggleButton
    x:Name="PumpBTN"
    IsThreeState="False"
    Checked="PumpBTN_C"
    Unchecked="PumpBTN_U"
    Content="Pump" />
```

2. Create a event subscription in `PrimaryPage.xaml.cs`

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using WinUI.XXXX.EventHandler; // Include EventHandler

namespace WinUI.XXXX.Views;

public partial class PrimaryPage : Page // Unsealed
{
    public PrimaryViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get;
    }

    public PrimaryPage()
    {
        ViewModel = App.GetService<PrimaryViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();

        Event event = new Event();
        PumpBTN.Checked += event.PumpBTN_C; // Pump-checked subscription
        PumpBTN.Unchecked += event.PumpBTN_U; // Pump-unchecked subscription
    }
}
```

3. Create a event handler in `EventHandler.cs`:

```cs
using System.IO.Ports;
using WinUI.XXXX.Views;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace WinUI.XXXX.EventHandler;

public partial class Event
{
    public readonly SerialPort serial_port = new();

    public Serial()
    {
        Main();
    }

    public string Main()
    {
        // Serial port stuffs
        return 'strings' // Just for an example
    }

    public void PumpBTN_C(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Event handler
    {
        // Code
    }
    public void PumpBTN_U(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Event handler
    {
        // Code
    }
```

I think I alredy do everything that I needed to, I aleady type `using` followed by the corresponding namespaces, I already subscribe and create a event handler as needed.

I'm just started developing GUI with C# and XAML in WinUI3 a few weeks ago, and I've no experience in writing in [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) languages before, So I have no idea what should I do next. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) and bind the `IsChecked`-property instead? If this model is used you would avoid code behind as much as possible, and instead put this in a "view model"-class, using bindings to synchronize the view and viewModel.

Comment: I've read through your comment and I researched more about it and that's a very good way to go, I've fixed the problem using your method and it seems to work fine!

I'll answer my own question soon using your advice as guidance, Thanks for your advice! That's helping me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way is to use MVVM to bind the IsChecked property of the *View* to a property in the *ViewModel*:

view

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyIsCheckedProperty}">
Pump
</CheckBox>
```

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool myIsCheckedValue;
    public bool MyIsCheckedProperty
    {
        get => myIsCheckedValue;
        set
        {
            if (value != myIsCheckedValue)
            {
                myIsCheckedValue = value;                
                OnPropertyChanged();
                // Do other stuff
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You can add an event to your `MyViewModel`, and raise it at the `// Do other stuff` point to inform other components. Or just make a call to some method to inform it that the checkbox has changed. The idea with the pattern is that the "ViewModel" classes should interact with and update a "Model" that represents the overall state of your application.

Note that you will need to ensure the DataContext object of your view is set to the viewModel object. For example by using a little bit of code behind:

```
public partial class MyMainWindow : Window
{
        private MainWindowViewModel mwmv;
        public MyMainWindow ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MyViewModel;
        }
}
```

This is typically only done for the root window, and use bindings to associate any other views with viewModels. This needs to be done since all bindings are relative to the DataContextObject.

Answer (score 2):

**According to [JonasH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12342238/jonash) suggestions:**

> Have you considered using MVVM and bind the IsChecked-property
> instead? If this model is used you would avoid code behind as much as
> possible, and instead put this in a "view model"-class, using bindings
> to synchronize the view and viewModel.

Here's how I applied it to my code.

First I moved the `EventHandler.cs` (which contains an event handler for XAML `ToggleButton`) to a `ViewModel` folder according to [MVVM Design Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern))

Then, I create an **EventHandler** function on `EventHandler.cs`:

```cs
using System.IO.Ports;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;

namespace WinUI.XXXX.ViewModels.Event;

public partial class EventHandler
{
    public void PumpBTN_C(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle the event
    }
    
    public void PumpBTN_U(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle the event
    }
}
```

Make sure to import necessary namespaces in `PrimaryPage.xaml.cs`, then create a field named 'Event' which is linked to an `EventHandler` class in `EventHandler.cs`:

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using WinUI.XXXX.ViewModels;
using WinUI.XXXX.ViewModels.Event;

namespace WinUI.XXXX.Views;

public partial class PrimaryPage : Page // Unsealed
{
    EventHandler Event = new(); // Create a field named 'Event'

    public PrimaryPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

After that, bind the `IsChecked` property on `ToggleButton` in XAML files to the **EventHandler** function:

```xml
<ToggleButton
    IsThreeState="False"
    Checked="{x:Bind Event.PumpBTN_C}"
    Unchecked="{x:Bind Event.PumpBTN_U}"
    Content="Pump" />
```

In this way, you can now create an `EventHandler` and then bind the `ToggleButton` to the event handler in a whole different class (or files)

P.S. I'm new to C# GUI development, so if anyone has a clearer or more efficient way to explain this topic, please provide your insight or ideas down below.

Comment: A tip: avoid calling things `EventHandler`, since this is a existing .net type, and using the same name will likely lead to confusion or conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

The event handler itself *must* be defined in the same class as the XAML element.

What you can do is to pass along the arguments to the method of your other class and perform any work in there, e.g.:

```
public PrimaryPage()
{
    ViewModel = App.GetService<PrimaryViewModel>();
    InitializeComponent();

    Event event = new Event();
    PumpBTN.Checked += (s,e) => event.PumpBTN_C(s, e);
    PumpBTN.Unchecked += (s,e) => event.PumpBTN_U(s, e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance! While I didn't use your method in the code, your response was still very helpful and appreciated. Since I already found a way to fix the problems, I'll post the answer to my own question soon! Thanks again for your advice!